# Internal server error when passing Map<Id, SObject> from Lightning to Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, gack

I am temporarily storing changes to records in a Map by Id in my Lightning component

**Markup:**

```
<aura:component controller="MyController">
     <aura:attribute name="changes" type="Map" default="{}" access="private" /> 
     ...
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller Code:**

```
var changes = cmp.get("v.changes");
changes[recordId] = {
   sobjectType: 'NAMESPACE__MyCustomRecord__c',
   Id: recordId,
   ...
};
cmp.set("v.changes", changes);

var action = cmp.get("c.save");  
action.setParams({
        changes: cmp.get("v.changes")
    });
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void save(Map<Id, SObject> changes) {
    update changes.values();
}
```

When I invoke this the Apex save() method throws an

> An internal server error has occurred Error ID: 1757078119-115612
>   (1843984413) Error

Comment: why are you not passing just list of objects

Comment: In Javascript I need a Map by Id to store changes in the same object. But you are right I could pass only the values() of this map. How would I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values here is a link to do .. but you can check browser support for that function

Comment: a more cleaner way is to make a object like { id : 'recordid', object : {sobject} }

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157732/how-to-send-javascript-map-as-a-parameter-from-lightning-component-to-apex-serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to change my Apex method to not work on generic `SObject` but a concrete type `Account`.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void save(Map<Id, Account> changes) {
    update changes.values();
}
```

After that everything worked.

Comment: Whenever I run into that I just JSON.stringify and deserialize in the apex method